# Function doing integer comparison in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, comparison-operators

I am writing a variadic template function which compare multiple integer.
I would like to use it this way :

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
bool multiple_comparison(T first, bool(* compar)(T&, T&), T second, Args... args){
    return compar(first, second) && multiple_comparison(second, args...);
} 

int main(){
  multiple_comparison(1, <, 3); //should return true
  return 0;
}
```

However, I have compilation issue:

```
  error: no matches converting function ‘operator<’ to type ‘bool (*)(int&, int&)’
```

I guess it is because this is not this function that is used for primitive type.
I found the "std::less" (and the others operators) online, but it is C++14 and I am stuck with C++11.

Is there a way to do it ? Because, for the moment, the only thing I can think of is replacing every comparison operator by a custom function.

Thanks.

Comment: ... and why don't you check your system header files (probably `functional`) on how `std::less` is defined? The operator prototype is probably `(const T&, const T&) -> bool`. But why don't you use a template for that?

Comment: [Does not work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/) is not an useful problem description.

Comment: @dhke can you give me more details about your solution ? I do not understand it.

Comment: Please, can you show us a minimal, but complete, example of the code that give you the compilation errors?

Comment: @Viridya Please, provide an example of what your function is supposed to achieve and pinpoint where you are stuck. you are asking for a particular solution without providing the bigger picture. Which --especially in very language specific cases-- usually yields not the answers you want.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I edited the post to add the function and the error I have.

Comment: @Viridya Please provide an [mcve]. Currently, your code does not seem to correspond to the error that you are getting (`operator<` is not used anywhere).

Comment: I feel like maybe they should just make it a policy that anyone who is posting about a compiler error has to have a coliru (or equivalent) link. Full stop. Would save so much time.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Mea culpa, I added it now :)

Comment: @Viridya And, yet, it still isn't [mcve]. Minimal? Yes. Complete, and in-turn, verifiable? No.

Comment: @Viridya `std::less` is C++98 at the very least. And the usual trick here is to have the comparator as a template: `class Compare = std::less<T>` and then call `Comparator()(a, b)`. The standard lib does this all the time (but usually with the comparator as an instance variable so that it's only constructed once). There's usually no global `operator<()` function.

Comment: AlgirdasPreidžius I provided an entire compilable code, hoping it is enough, otherwise, I just do not understand what you are expecting... Sorry.
@dhke Could you give an entire example ? Because I might not know something about template since I never saw something like "class X = Y".
By the way, indeed less exist for a moment, I read too fast and just saw the "Since C++14".

Comment: Your code was closer to working when you used `operator<` in `main`; then you had a compiler error but it at least parsed. It still didn’t work because, as you pointed out, `operator<` isn’t actually defined that way. There are some other errors beyond the scope of this question as well.

Answer (score 3):

*Whatever* you want to achieve, this is not the way we do it in C++.
This is more idiomatic, (and works in any C++ pre C++11).

```
#include<functional>  //for std::less
template<typename T, class Comparison>
bool multiple_comparison(T first, Comparison comp, T second){
    return comp(first, second);
} 

int main(){
  multiple_comparison(1, std::less<int>(), 3); //should return true
}
```

I removed the variadic argument part because that was not part of the question and the recursion was wrong.

---

EDIT: From the comments *I deduce* that this is what you want.

> Even mathematicians will agree that want you want to implement is a
>   dangerous abuse of notation (for example if you drop a `std::greater`
>   in the middle of the sequence everyone will be confused)

Here it is anyway:

```
#include<utility> //for std::forward
template<typename T>
constexpr bool multiple_comparison(T const& second){return true;} 

template<typename T, class Compare, class... Rest>
bool multiple_comparison(T const& first, Compare comp, T const& second, Rest&&... rest){
    return comp(first, second) and multiple_comparison(second, std::forward<Rest>(rest)...);
} 

#include<functional>  //for std::less and equal
#include<cassert>
int main(){
  // is    1 < 3 == 3 < 5 ?
  assert( multiple_comparison(1, std::less<int>(), 3, std::equal_to<int>(), 3, std::less<int>(), 5) );
  // is    1 < 3 == 4 < 5 ?
  assert( not multiple_comparison(1, std::less<int>(), 3, std::equal_to<int>(), 4, std::less<int>(), 5) );

// bonus for C++11, explicit type omitted
  assert( multiple_comparison(1, std::less<>(), 3, std::equal_to<>(), 3, std::less<>(), 5) );
  assert( not multiple_comparison(1, std::less<>(), 3, std::equal_to<>(), 4, std::less<>(), 5) );

}
```

Comment: Ok, my bad, I guess you did not understand my problem.
I want to do something like "multiple_comparison(1, < , 3 , == , 5 , < , 6). This is why I use variadic template ^^.
Still, Thanks for the example. I will use "less" and the other functions remplacing operators.

Comment: Interesting, so you want   `A comp1 B comp2 C comp3 D` to mean `A comp1 B` and `B comp2 C` and `C comp3 D`?

Comment: @Viridya Then edit the question accordingly please. We couldn't have guessed that you want this exact syntax.

Comment: @alfC Yep, I am working on a compiler and some of the library I use for analysis return me code that look like "A comp1 B comp2 C comp3 D" but since it is not valid, I must transform that.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison functions in `functional` existed before C++14; they just changed slightly in that release. If you look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), you see that before C++14, they didn’t have a default value for `T` and you had to specify it yourself, but they still existed.

If those functions had not existed, you could have written lambdas which used the operators directly (like `[](const T& lhs, const T& rhs) { return lhs < rhs; }`).